# "Could not find or load main class org.opengts.util.CompiletimeVars" error with Ant

Tags: java, ant, opengts

I am working on OpenGTS and I am trying to compile it using build.xml with the command `ant all`. I keep on getting this error:

> [java] Error: Could not find or load main class org.opengts.util.CompiletimeVars
>
> Java returned: 1

Code:

```
<!-- (re)create compile time source file here? -->
<echo message="Creating CompileTime module ..."/>
<java classname="org.opengts.util.CompiletimeVars" fork="true" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="-configFileDir=${basedir}"/>
    <arg value="-template?=${basedir}/CompileTime.jtemp"/>
    <arg value="-package=org.opengts"/>
    <arg value="-output=${src.gts}/org/opengts/CompileTime.java"/>
    <arg value="-overwrite=false"/> <!-- do not overwrite -->
    <arg value="-extra=${CompiletimeVars.extra}"/>
    <arg value="${CompiletimeVars.arg}"/>
    <arg value="${CompiletimeVars.arg.1}"/>
    <arg value="${CompiletimeVars.arg.2}"/>
    <arg value="${CompiletimeVars.arg.3}"/>
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${build.lib}/gtsutils.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</java>
```

Comment: the class is in the openGTS installation folder in a sub folder src/org/opengts/util  thanx in advance!

Comment: are you running the ant task in the class directory?

Comment: @Nazarine If the class "org.opengts.util.CompiletimeVars" is missing at runtime, but available as source, that implies elsewhere within the ANT build file there is an attempt to compile the source code. What you're missing in the classpath is an addition entry pointing to the compiled classes.